# storageReference.downloadURL with completion handler... url keeps returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

For some reason, when I am using firebase storage to retrieve my download image URL (I have confirmed that the image is actually sent to firebase storage), the url is returning nil. I'm pretty sure my file path matches/is correct but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong on this.

```
let selectedImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage.image!, 1)
    let storageRef=Storage.storage().reference()
    let metadata=StorageMetadata()
    storageRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        .child("Pictures"+String(self.tracker)).putData(selectedImageData!, metadata: metadata) 
    { 
        (metadata, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("There was a problem uploading")
            return
        }

        storageRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
            .child("Pictures"+String(self.tracker)).downloadURL(completion: 
        { 
            (url, error) in

            print("What's going on")
            self.pictures.append((url?.absoluteString)!)
        })
    }
```

Comment: In the downloadUrl completion handler you are also getting an Error?.
Can you print it?
 Maybe it says the reason for failure

Comment: on the debug console, it says the url is equal to nil- that is why I am saying the completion handler has an error. Other than that, it doesn't say anything else.

Comment: Below your line `print("What's going on")` add this line and let me know what is printed in your debug console: `print("Download url error: \(error)")`

Comment: Download url error: Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object Users/0kOuKzm2ukbLtlddYBXXcxVxfeq1/Pictures5 does not exist." UserInfo={object=Users/0kOuKzm2ukbLtlddYBXXcxVxfeq1/Pictures5, bucket=wemic-f9613.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"
  }

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to upload image to Storage and get a return path for the image

```
let selectedImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage.image!, 1)
self.uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data: selectedImageData)

func uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data:NSData){

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Pictures").child(String(self.tracker)) 
//Modify the above line as per your requirement

if data != nil {
    storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }

        // Fetch the download URL
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle any errors
                if(error != nil){
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            } else {
                // Get the download URL
                let urlStr:String = (url?.absoluteString) ?? ""
                print(urlStr)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and this worked for me. There was a glitch in the referemces. the absolute string requires a reference to the image "file", and not to the "Folder"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your reference for putData and for getting downloadURL is different some how, maybe the tracker is changing in the meantime?

To avoid the reference being different let's try changing your code like this:

```
let selectedImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage.image!, 1)
let storageRef=Storage.storage().reference()
let metadata=StorageMetadata()
let reference = storageRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Pictures"+String(self.tracker))
reference.putData(selectedImageData!, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print("There was a problem uploading")
        return
    }
    reference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        print("Download error: \(error), url: \(url)")
        self.pictures.append((url?.absoluteString)!)
    }
}
```

Basically we make sure to use the same reference in both cases.